# Scale layer in Photoshop without changing aspect ratio?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, resize

I need to scale a layer, make it smaller. But when I try to scale it down with **Edit > Transform > Scale**, it's a type of scaling that can change the aspect ratio.

I'm looking for a scale feature that forces the aspect ratio of the layer to be maintained while shrinking or enlarging it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The link button in-between the width and height boxes will maintain the aspect ratio.

You can also hold <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> while dragging the transform handles.

[image]

As always, the information is in the Photoshop help documentation:

- [Photoshop Help / Transform objects](https://helpx.adobe.com/photoshop/using/transforming-objects.html#scale_rotate_skew_distort_apply_perspective_or_warp)

Comment: This used to work (I've been using Photoshop since 2.0) but doesn't anymore.

Comment: This does not work in the newest version of Photoshop any longer, but worked in all previous versions.